# In Kubernetes cluster with haproxy, 2 masters, 1 node. When master1 is down, the failover not working

Tags: kubernetes

Implemented on Oracle VM as per the document, but failover didn't work.

https://github.com/justmeandopensource/kubernetes/tree/master/kubeadm-ha-multi-master

```
Role                    FQDN                    IP       OS             RAM CPU
Load Balancer   loadbalancer.example.com172.16.16.100   Ubuntu 20.04    1G  1
Master          kmaster1.example.com    172.16.16.101   Ubuntu 20.04    2G  2
Master          kmaster2.example.com    172.16.16.102   Ubuntu 20.04    2G  2
Worker          kworker1.example.com    172.16.16.201   Ubuntu 20.04    1G  1

Below are the details before shutting down the kmaster1 and after. 

root@kmaster2:~# kubectl get nodes
NAME       STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
kmaster1   Ready    master   22h   v1.19.2
kmaster2   Ready    master   22h   v1.19.2
kworker1   Ready    <none>   22h   v1.19.2
===>shutdown now on master1-========
root@kmaster2:~# kubectl get nodes
Error from server: etcdserver: request timed out
root@kmaster2:~# kubectl get nodes
Error from server: etcdserver: request timed out
root@kmaster2:~# ping 172.16.16.100
PING 172.16.16.100 (172.16.16.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.16.16.100: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.580 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.16.100: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.716 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.16.100: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.08 ms
^C
--- 172.16.16.100 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2053ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.580/0.792/1.081/0.211 ms
root@kmaster2:~# kubectl get nodes
Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
root@kmaster2:~# kubectl get nodes
Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

Comment: What about your `etcd` server ? Is it running ? For some reason it cannot be reached: `Error from server: etcdserver: request timed out`

Comment: mario, i guess this is stacked etcd server, where master1 goes down, all the cluster mainly with apiserver goes down. am i correct? i think for HA we need to use external etcd server. please suggst.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Any progress in resolving this issue during that time ? Well, it's really hard to say. Does `etcd` server run in cluster ? What about running `kubectl get pods -n kube-system` ? Does it show two separate pods running `etcd` on two separate master nodes ? What happens if you shutdown one master ? Does it show any of `etcd` pods running after that ?